# DDL with Index and Hash Partition on Postgres Aurora

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora

Hi i am trying to create a DDL in PostgreSQL Aurora with Hash partition on OBJECT_ID.
Also i want to create a Index on `CUSTOMER_ID,OBJECT_TYPE,OBJECT_ID,PT_EVENT_ID`

```
CREATE TABLE event_test(
   ID varchar(255) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   VERSION int(11) NOT NULL,
   ORDER_TYPE varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   EVENT_TYPE varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   CUSTOMER_ID varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   DETAILS text,
   OBJECT_TYPE varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   UTC_DATE_TIME date DEFAULT NULL,
   EVENT_TO_UTC_DT date DEFAULT NULL,
   GROUP_ID varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   OBJECT_NAME  varchar(2001) DEFAULT NULL,
   OBJECT_ID  varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   USER_NAME  varchar(1500) DEFAULT NULL,
   USER_ID  varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   PT_EVENT_ID  varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   CUSTOM_NOTES  varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
   SUMMARY  varchar(4000) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

Can some please help me with the DDL .

Comment: Note that `varchar(255)` is not by any means more efficient than `varchar(257)` - the 255 limit does not open up any magic performance optimizations if you expected that.

Comment: Are those IDs numbers? If yes, you should better store them in `integer` or `bigint` columns. Don't store everything in `varchar(255)`. And `int(11)´ is not valid for Postgres to begin with

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so ID is GUID thanks for the quick help

Comment: Then you should use the `uuid` data type.

Comment: Ohh i dd not know we have such data type ..I am directly going from Mysql to Postgress so doing this silly mistakes

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe i want to use hash partition because most of the my access is based on Object_id   guid again .I have 10 TB size of the table and i do not have any column on which data can be distributed

Comment: And start by normalising your data. {USER_ID,USER_NAME,OBJECT_ID,OBJECT_NAME,...} look like they belong in separate tables.

Comment: @wildplasser Yes correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all those IDs are in fact UUIDs, the columns should be defined with the `uuid` type.

The supposedly "magic" limit of 255 does not enable some hidden performance or storage optimizations (at least in Postgres). So blindly using `varchar(255)` doesn't really make sense (of course if you have a valid business requirement that a value for  `order_type` or `event_type` may never be longer than 255 characters, then of course keep that constraint.

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html) there is also no "length" parameter for the `integer` data type (and it's not a value restriction in MySQL either, so it's pretty much useless to begin with).

So the DDL should be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE event_test(
   ID              uuid PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   VERSION         integer NOT NULL,
   ORDER_TYPE      varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   EVENT_TYPE      varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   CUSTOMER_ID     uuid DEFAULT NULL,
   DETAILS         text,
   OBJECT_TYPE     varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   UTC_DATE_TIME   date DEFAULT NULL,
   EVENT_TO_UTC_DT date DEFAULT NULL,
   GROUP_ID        uuid DEFAULT NULL,
   OBJECT_NAME     varchar(2001) DEFAULT NULL,
   OBJECT_ID       uuid DEFAULT NULL,
   USER_NAME       varchar(1500) DEFAULT NULL,
   USER_ID         uuid DEFAULT NULL,
   PT_EVENT_ID     uuid DEFAULT NULL,
   CUSTOM_NOTES    varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
   SUMMARY         varchar(4000) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

To create an index, you use create index:

```
create index on event_test (customer_id,object_type,object_id,pt_event_id);
```

If "most of your access" is through the `object_id` then you need an index where that is the leading column:

```
create index on event_test (object_id);
```

Hash partitioning won't really help you there to make things faster.

---

You *can* use partitioning for the table, but this is hardly a performance tool. Due to the limitations of the Postgres partitioning implementation you will also be forced to include the `id` column in the partitioning key if you want to keep that as the primary key. But given your statement that "most access is through `object_id` the partitioning key `(id, object_id)` wouldn't help you at all.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: true, I changed it to relate to performance

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are right about performance .But i have this single table 10 TB data without any partition .Also the limitation is not valid for psotgress 12.4 Aurora so we can create partition on a column which is not unique and not part of primary key

Comment: @AtharvThakur: I have no experience with Aurora, but with "vanilla" Postgres you can not use `partition by hash (object_id);`  as long as `id` is defined as a primary key. You would need to define the primary key as `(object_id, id)` if you want `partition by hash (object_id, id)` - but then `object_id` must be declared as `not null` which you currently don't have. It's still totally unclear what problem exactly you are trying to solve with "partitioning"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so there are other sets of challenges we are facing with this big tables like if we have delete rows from this big table partition can help also aggregation query on this table is very very slow so i think i can run long running query partition wise